# Noob Question on NodeLists and NodeMaps

Tags: java

I am trying to pull elements out of a parsed XML file by searching a specific node from a NodeList.  This is the following code I am using to iterate through multiple parents:

```
Node node;
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("SomeTag");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
{
     NamedNodeMap map = nodeList.item(i).getAttributes();
     node = map.getNamedItem("AnotherTag")
}
```

However, my node always returns null.  When doing some debugging, it appears it has all the values:
[image]

I think it has to do something with the "this$0" reference to itself before I get to the values, because if i do a getLength of the NodeMap, it returns 0.  Any thought on how to fix this?  Thanks a bunch everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the *attributes* of an element, not its sub-nodes by calling  `nodeList.item(i).getAttributes();`

Comment: I found an example that similarily does what I'm doing and they seem to be having better luck with it:  http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_attributes

Any thoughts as to why that works?  Here's the page:
http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_nodes_nodelist.asp

Comment: My guess is you are trying to access: <SomeTag>...<AnotherTag/>...</SomeTag>.   Correct?  In this case, you should just use nodeList.item(i) and check its name (and if it is of type Element). You are accessing the attributes, i.e. <SomeTag>...<sometag AnotherTag="bubulala">...</SomeTag>

Comment: Thanks for your help, you got me on the right track.  I was parsing names, addresses, and GPS locations from a response from a google maps query.  Here it is if anyone is interested: [Parse](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2190/parse.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Have you maybe thought about using JAXB?

You could create Java objects and have JAXB load the XML file and walk through the tree in that way.  You can even create the Java objects automatically from the XSD, if you have one.

Comment: It's a trivial example of a trivial base usage of DOM in probably a trivial XML, is it really needed to tell the TS to go and switch to a different XML library, instead of the simpler answer, 'you're doing it wrong'?